# Engaging Core In Marching Band?

Tags: breathing, core

This year I am in marching band as a snare drum for my high school.
I was told to engage my core to make all my fundamentals (forwards, backwards, and sideways marching) smoother, and to keep my drumsticks together when I'm not playing.

But, when I try to engage my core, I find I cant breath, and it doesn't really help my marching. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does "engaging your core" mean?

Comment: That is  what I am asking... What do they mean by engaging my core, and am I doing it right?

Comment: You say, "when I try to engage my core, I find I can't breath". So what do you mean when you say you're engaging your core? What are you doing when this happens, just flexing your abs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that your teacher is telling you to get your shoulders back (don't hunch over) and stand straight up.  You don't need to flex anything though.  But when you are doing something like marching (think Army) you need to have your back straight and perpendicular to the ground, your steps need to firm.

If your posture is bad when you normally walk it will take practice.  And of you should feel a little out of breath keeping your body in a position you are not used to, especially when doing something else.